# How to find the cumulative distribution function of slope of line?

Tags: probability

Trying to solve this problem:

Choose a point uniformly at random inside the unit square with corners at (0; 0), (1; 0), (0; 1) and (1; 1). Let S be the slope of the line through the chosen point and the origin. 
Find the cumulative distribution function of S

Help, please!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $(X,Y)\sim\text{Unif}[0,1]^2$, then the joint pdf factors as
$$
I_{[0,1]}^2(x,y)=I_{[0,1]}(x)I_{[0,1]}(y).
$$
In particular $X,Y$ are i.i.d $\text{Unif}[0,1]$. We are after the distribution $Y/X$. For the cdf see this stats [stackexchange link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15522/distribution-of-a-ratio-of-uniforms-what-is-wrong).