# Distribution of slope of the line

Tags: probability

Choose a point uniformly at random inside the unit square with
corners at (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1). Let S be the slope of the line through the
chosen point and the origin.
Find the cumulative distribution function of S.

So far, I denoted the coordinates of points (X,Y). Then $S = \frac{Y}{X}$. Is it right to assume that  $X,Y \sim Unif[0,1]$. And how then do I find the distribution of S? And are there any other more elegant ways to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the cumulative distribution function of slope of line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550790/how-to-find-the-cumulative-distribution-function-of-slope-of-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cdf. is the area of the triangle enclosed in the unit square to the right of $y=Sx$

for $S \le 1$

$$  F(S)= \frac S2    $$

notice that ...

$$   F (\frac 1S) = 1-F(S) $$
So for $S>1$
$$F(S) = 1-\frac1{2S}  $$